# Error while trying to install custom package on Julia

Tags: package, julia

I am trying to install a custom package in Julia using command `Pkg.add(PackageSpec(path = ""))`, which is in my local directory. I created my package using the [Julia documentation](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/). But every time when I am trying to install my custom package using [PackageSpec](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/api/) from my local path it throws an error. The folowing error is -

```
Cloning git-repo `D:\df_sql\src\df_sql.jl`
ERROR: failed to clone from D:\df_sql\src\df_sql.jl, error: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:Net, failed to resolve address for D: No such host is known. )
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Types.jl:120
 [2] #clone#2(::Nothing, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Any,Tuple{Symbol,Symbol},NamedTuple{(:isbare, :credentials),Tuple{Bool,LibGit2.CachedCredentials}}}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\GitTools.jl:107
 [3] #handle_repos_add!#32(::Bool, ::Nothing, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at .\none:0
 [4] #handle_repos_add! at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [5] #add_or_develop#15(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:59
 [6] #add_or_develop#14 at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [7] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#10 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:32 [inlined]
 [9] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add#20 at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:74 [inlined]
 [11] add(::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:74
 [12] top-level scope at none:0
```

My project Structure is-

[image]

I am using Julia version 1.6.0
Any idea how to solve the issue!!!

Comment: Hey, can you specify what commands you are trying to run to install the package? Where are you trying to install it?

Comment: Pkg.add(). I am trying to install it in my local machine julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to have an initialized Git repo in that folder to add it as a package. Here are the steps I made to get a package that I could install locally in Julia:

1. Setup

```
using Pkg
Pkg.generate("MyPackage")
open("MyPackage/src/MyPackage.jl","w") do f
    println(f, """
module MyPackage
foo(what) = println("Hello " * what)
export foo
end
    """)
end
```

2. Press `;` to go to the command line shell mode:

```
shell> cd MyPackage

shell> git init

shell> git add *

shell> git commit -m init

shell> cd ..
```

3. Now you can install the package

```
julia> Pkg.add(path="MyPackage")
     Cloning git-repo `C:\temp\MyP\MyPackage`
    Updating git-repo `C:\temp\MyP\MyPackage`
    Updating registry at `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.7.0\registries\General.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.7.0\environments\v1.7\Project.toml`
  [7e0d665f] + MyPackage v0.1.0 `..\..\..\..\temp\MyP\MyPackage#master`
    Updating `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.7.0\environments\v1.7\Manifest.toml`
  [7e0d665f] + MyPackage v0.1.0 `..\..\..\..\temp\MyP\MyPackage#master`
Precompiling project...
  1 dependency successfully precompiled in 5 seconds (316 already precompiled)
```

4. Package is installed so it can be used

```
julia> using MyPackage

julia> foo("world")
Hello world
```

#### Note

You could avoid initializing Git repo by using `Pkg.develop` instead, after step 1 from the above instruction you could do:

```
julia> Pkg.develop(path="MyPackage")
   Resolving package versions...
    Updating `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.7.0\environments\v1.7\Project.toml`
  [7e0d665f] + MyPackage v0.1.0 `..\..\..\..\temp\MyP\MyPackage`
    Updating `C:\JuliaPkg\Julia-1.7.0\environments\v1.7\Manifest.toml`
  [7e0d665f] + MyPackage v0.1.0 `..\..\..\..\temp\MyP\MyPackage`

julia> using MyPackage
[ Info: Precompiling MyPackage [7e0d665f-f51f-4097-93d9-367fa446d15a]

julia> foo("world")
Hello world
```

Comment: using Pk.develop giving error- ERROR: could not find project file in package at `//media//sourodip//Data//df_sql//src` maybe `subdir` needs to be specified

Comment: You need to be careful with the folders. If you run it exactly as in my example it will work (I tested this code). `Pkg.develop` needs to be run in the folder being a parent of your package folder (see my examples)

Comment: Sorry my bad file name was missing but now facing another issue after providing correct file . ERROR: Dev path `//media//sourodip//Data//df_sql//src//df_sql.jl` is a file, but a directory is required.

Comment: Hi, please look carefully at my codes - maybe try first exactly running my codes? You should provide folder name not file name